# Password and confirm password does not match

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Password and confirm password does not match.
Even if you write the same password in both fields gives me error and says passwords does not match.

This is how Account looks like:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

And this is the register page:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

I searched on google and this forum , but I have not found anything that works.

Can someone help me ?

Here is the database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D86QV.png

You can try to register: http://ursaciucadrian.somee.com/Home/Register?Length=4

Comment: What is your question? What issues are your having?

Comment: Even if you write the same password in both fields gives me error and says passwords does not match.

Comment: Edit you question to make it clear what your issue is. But the code you have shown works fine.

Comment: What about other validation? Do you get required validation?

Comment: And here is a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4CE4cw) to prove your code works

Comment: Your linked images show it is working (the second image shows the error message when the values no not match)! What do you think your problem is? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It is the same password in both fields and tells me are not the same

Comment: You second image shows the text "password" in the `Password` textbox and an empty string in the `ConfirmPassword` textbox. What makes you think "password" and "" are the same?

Comment: 2nd image is after i click create.

Comment: Exactly, because the values are not the same, you get an error message.What make you think you shouldn't?

Comment: i will make a video for you

Comment: I'm not going to look at a video!. You code works! And I have created a fiddle to prove it as well (see the link above and try it out). If your claiming its not working, then it has got nothing to do with the code you have shown here.

Comment: So what could it be? maybe something to the database ?

Comment: Could you show the `Register` action code too?

Comment: I can't right now. Her is 11 pm and i am on phone. I will put it tomorrow

Comment: Is this a joke? You link to a site that works correctly and then claim it doesn't! Type a 6 letter word in the Password textbox and repeat it exactly in the Confirm Password textbox - your DO NOT get an error message when you click the Register button. But the fact you storing plain text passwords in a database shows you have far more serious problems than this. You store hashed values, not the password itself!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of tutorials and searches I realized that the problem was from scaffolding.

I had to change

```
public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include = "AccountId,FullName,Username,Password,Email")] Account account)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Accounts.Add(account);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(account);
    }
```

in this:

```
public ActionResult Register(Account account)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Accounts.Add(account);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(account);
    }
```

Comment: Delete your question. This is of no use to anyone. The code in your question works perfectly as did the site you linked to, and you did not include any code relating to the controller

Comment: Everything works fine if you just add 'ConfirmPassword' to the list of Bind parameters, instead of removing all of them. 

Like this:
public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include = "AccountId,FullName,Username,Password,Email,ConfirmPassword")] Account account)

Answer (score 0):

There was an old bug from [2013](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1401), Try to update all of the project's dependencies:

```
PM> update-package
```

Comment: No updates available for 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization' in project 'UrsaciucAdrian'.
No updates available for 'WebGrease' in project 'UrsaciucAdrian'.
.... and so on,

stil does not work